# How to remove the approved workflow from a copy of an approved document

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I am creating a new document copied from a workflow approved document, make amendments and to submit for workflow approval.

what happened is that, the copied document is already marked as approved and I am no longer allowed to submit workflow approval.

the option to create a new blank document will loose all the historical changes of the document.

need an advise how to submit the doc for approval given this scenario. Appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand you want to copy a file from one document library to another document library without approval status.

You could use "Copy list item" action in the workflow to copy file without approval status.